# Ruby: Time.parse() Incorrectly Returning Alaskan Timezone

Tags: ruby, datetime, timezone

In my app, I am using

```
> Time.parse('12:30 pm MDT').utc
=> 2015-06-08 18:30:00 UTC
> Time.parse('12:30 pm EDT').utc
=> 2015-06-08 16:30:00 UTC
> Time.parse('12:30 pm CDT').utc
=> 2015-06-08 17:30:00 UTC
> Time.parse('12:30 pm PDT').utc
=> 2015-06-08 19:30:00 UTC
> Time.parse('12:30 pm MST').utc
=> 2015-06-08 19:30:00 UTC
```

Which all works just fine, but as soon as I start asking for hawaii or alaskan timezones, it returns an incorrect result:

```
> Time.parse('12:30 pm HST').utc
=> 2015-06-08 12:30:00 UTC
> Time.parse('12:30 pm HAST').utc
=> 2015-06-08 12:30:00 UTC
> Time.parse('12:30 pm AKDT').utc
=> 2015-06-08 12:30:00 UTC
> Time.parse('12:30 pm AKST').utc
=> 2015-06-08 12:30:00 UTC
```

Even this does not work:

```
> Time.parse('12:30 pm -800').utc
=> 2015-06-08 12:30:00 UTC
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? And perhaps more importantly, does anyone have any advice about how to parse a time that is -800 or -900?

Comment: what Ruby version you are using?

Comment: It might be that your system doesn't know what those time-zones are. What operating system and version of Ruby are you using? Here ` Time.parse('12:30 pm HST').utc` produces `2015-06-08 16:30:00 UTC` on Ruby 2.1.5, OS X 10.10, though that's not Hawaii time.

Comment: I am also on 10.10 and ruby 2.1.1 and rails 4.1.1, but I did try with ruby 2.1.5, and that also produced  `2015-06-08 12:30:00 UTC`.  Your response f `Time.parse('12:30 pm HST').utc` producing `2015-06-08 16:30:00 UTC` is also concerning, it should produce `21:30:00 UTC`, right? Is this a ruby bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) of `Time.parse` contains (emphasis mine):

> Since there are numerous conflicts among locally defined time zone
>   abbreviations all over the world, this method is not intended to
>   understand all of them. For example, the abbreviation “CST” is used
>   variously as:
>
> ```
> -06:00 in America/Chicago,
> -05:00 in America/Havana,
> +08:00 in Asia/Harbin,
> +09:30 in Australia/Darwin,
> +10:30 in Australia/Adelaide,
> etc.
> ```
>
> Based on this fact, **this method only understands the time zone
>   abbreviations described in RFC 822 and the system time zone**, in the
>   order named. (i.e. a definition in RFC 822 overrides the system time
>   zone definition.) The system time zone is taken from `Time.local(year,
>   1, 1).zone` and `Time.local(year, 7, 1).zone`. **If the extracted time
>   zone abbreviation does not match any of them, it is ignored and the
>   given time is regarded as a local time.**

The following is from the syntax description in [RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) (5.1):

```
 zone        =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                             ; North American : UT
             /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
             /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
             /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
             /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
             /  1ALPHA                       ; Military: Z = UT;
                                             ;  A:-1; (J not used)
                                             ;  M:-12; N:+1; Y:+12
             / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential
                                             ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
```

As you can see your timezone names aren't mentioned. You have to write `-0800` and `-0900` as the leading zero is required (to match the `4DIGIT` part). If you want or have to keep the names, the more sophisticated [`DateTime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) class can be used.

```
Time.parse('12:30 pm -0800').utc # => 2015-06-08 20:30:00 UTC
DateTime.parse('12:30 pm AKDT').to_time.utc # => 2015-06-08 20:30:00 UTC
```